# gdb refresh symbols from libs loaded at runtime

Tags: linux, gdb

I am working on a application that loads several plugin libs at runtime. gdb loads and correctly debugs these, but if I make a change in the plugin gdb doesn't get the updated symbols so I have to clear everything and reset breakpoints again.

How can i get gdb to refresh runtime loaded plugins (ala symbol-file) without forgetting breakpoint locations?

Comment: Did you try to use GDB's [`file`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-file) command before every `run` ? Are the plugins recompiled every time?

Comment: wouldn't that make it forget which executable file to run? Or do you mean 'file path/to/app'? If the second, would it also forget all the arguments I used for the last run?

Comment: I thought of `file path/to/app`. IIRC, a next `run` takes the same program arguments, but that does not matter, you can use `run` with your arguments and most importantly you can use [`define`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html) to make your own "gdb macrocommand"

Comment: unfortunately, this app is run with a lot of arguments so typing them out is often more hassle than resetting breakpoints. I'll look at the macro command as another possible workaround, but I was hoping there'd be something a little more straighforwrad